# How to use Sharedpreferences for Uri in below page, Basically I want When I start my app I need that song in the player where from I closed my app

Tags: java, android-studio, sharedpreferences

here it is player

```
private void initPlayer(final int position) {

    if (mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
    }

    String sname = mySongs.get(position).getName().replace(".mp3", "").replace(".m4a", "").replace(".wav", "").replace(".m4b", "");
    songTitle.setText(sname);

    // I am taking the song data as uri

    Uri songResourceUri = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());

    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), songResourceUri); // create and load mediaplayer with song resources
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            String totalTime = createTimeLabel(mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
            totTime.setText(totalTime);
            mSeekBar.setMax(mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            playIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop);

        }
    });
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I want to use Sharedpreferences in my media player,   but I don't know how to use.                               Basically I want  the last song where from I closed my app